# Error running update query in Postgres NPGSQL - ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "="

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am running the following update command:

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE \"FPConfig_simulationresult\" SET key_name = :keyName WHERE id = :resultID", conn);

  command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("keyName", DbType.String));
  command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("resultID", DbType.Int32));
  command.Parameters[0].Value = keyName;
  command.Parameters[1].Value = resultID;
  int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and get the error:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "="
```

I have checked everything in the update SQL statement, the table name and field names are correct.

Comment: Could you show us the entire piece of SQL? Check the logfiles from the database server.

Comment: Also, can you add your postgresql and NPGSQL versions...

Comment: You can also check the ErrorSql property of the NpgsqlException which will show you the sql which gave the error. I hope it helps.